# Animations in pdf-documents on ipad

Tags: asymptote, animations

I am making documents with animations using LaTeX and Asymptote to produce pdf-animations that are included in the document. The resulting pdf-documents work fine when I use Acrobat Reader on a computer (Mac or PC), but they do not work on my Ipad.

Why is that, and is there a way to fix it? Or is there a better way to produce the document so that it works on tabloids as well?

Comment: It might very well be that the features normally used to enable the animations (you do not mention how you make the animations) are not supported in the PDF viewers for iPad and similar small devices. Might be left out out of security reasons.

Comment: I don't think you can expect interactive/animation pdf features to work on an iPad.